# Any simple way to migrate to strict MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have to make a huge application work with a newer MariaDB version. The version currently in use doesn't use any sql_mode rules, while newer versions are stricter and returns errors for things like forgetting to insert a value for a field that is not null.

Is there any simple way to migrate?

I was hoping that sql_mode rules could be used to log warnings instead of throwing errors, but I can't find anything like that. If that does exist then it would be great as I could simply start with logging warnings, fix them, and then go to the default which returns errors instead.

I've also looked at performance_schema for logging, and while it does log some warnings, it doesn't seem to log warnings for everything that newer MariaDB versions throws errors for.

And idea on how I can do this, without adding IGNORE to every INSERT/UPDATE statement to convert errors to warnings?

One would think that it included a setting or simple way of doing this, but I can't fint anything.

I hope someone has some knowledge of how this can be done.

Comment: You could add IGNORE to every INSERT/UPDATE query in the project with a simple command line using `awk` but there's no way anyone can tell you whatever this is something you should do or if that would be a dumb and potentially dangerous way to update your application. Those things need testing and a security evaluation.

Comment: There are no tools AFAIK which automatically can upgrade your code to the ANSI standard.  Best practice is to always try to stick with ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `sql_mode` on a newer version of MySQL to match the value you were using on your current version. It's only the default `sql_mode` that has changed. You can set the option to anything you want.

You can also change `sql_mode` in your code, so it takes effect only temporarily in a given session. So you could leave the mode as non-strict by default, then before each SQL query run by your app, enable strict mode and then reset to non-strict mode after the query.

This way you could test every query one at a time, while leaving the default as non-strict until you have debugged each case of an SQL query.

Once you've assured yourself all queries work in strict mode, set that as the default globally, and remove all the special cases in your code.

This will be a lot of work, but it's a simple, straightforward method.